# How to copy multiple elements to clipboard in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, clipboard

My aim is to copy multiple row content from Flex datagrid, to a clipboard enabling users to take pieces of information and pasting them were they are necessary.
I bumped into a problem that in Flex (as far as I know) its not possible to paste whole array of information in the clipboard.

At the moment, I pass selected datagrid items to a textfield, and then run 
"System.setClipboard(text_area.text);"

I was wonderng if there is a way to pass it to multiple Clipboard directories, without overwriting previous entry, similar as when you can copy multiple items from different location into a clipboard, pile them up and then paste all at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex can put any string value into a clipboard.  It doesn't support--as far as I know--complex values, such as arrays.  That said, you can convert your array into something along the lines of a comma or tab delimited file.

Separate rows using carriage return and line feeds.  Separate columns using commas tabs.  Conceptually something like this:

```
resultString += row1Column1 + ',' + row1Column2 + '\r\n';
resultString += row2Column1 + ',' + row2Column2 + '\r\n';
```

You didn't tell us how / why you want to preserve formatting.  I know cutting and pasting from Flex to Excel will recongnize the carriage return / line feeds as rows.  I do  not know if it will automatically detect multiple columns using a comma or tab, though.

Comment: I've done the same thing.  If you have a user action of 'copying' you can easily take whatever rows he's selected and transform it into one string to be copied to clipboard.  The formatting is up to you.